# Import classes from external SWF

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a bunch of classes in an SWF file. I'd like to use them in my Flash project. How do I import them?

External SWF

```
package com.external
{
    public class Class1 {}
}
```

In my project I want to write

```
import com.external.*;

var myclass:Class1 = new Class1();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
loader.load(new URLRequest("external.swf"));
function onLoad(e:Event):void
{
  var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(e.target);
  var loadedSWF:DisplayObject = loaderInfo.content;
  var ClassType:Class = loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("com.external.Class1") as Class;
  var t:Object = new ClassType();
}
```